# Halide how to autotune schedule

Tags: c++, halide

I'v been tring writing code in Halide for some time now and I was always writing schedules by my self. Then I read this paper: http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/halidesched/mullapudi16_halidesched.pdf. Soo what i understand, there is some way of generating best schedule. How can I possible do that?

Thanks for answers!

Edit:

Hello. I tried pulling branch and building it with CMAKE. But i have problem compiling Halide with it:

this is error in VS 2015:

```
4>  D:/halideAutoScheduler2/Halide.build/Release\initmod.aarch64_cpu_features_32.ll -> D:/halideAutoScheduler2/Halide.build/Release\initmod.aarch64_cpu_features_32.bc
4>  C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin\llvm-as.exe: D:/halideAutoScheduler2/Halide.build/Release\initmod.aarch64_cpu_features_32.ll:23:6: error: expected type
4>  !0 = !{!"clang version 3.6.0 (tags/RELEASE_360/final)"}
4>       ^
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Very brief answer...

Pull this branch: https://github.com/halide/Halide/tree/auto_scheduler

Take a piece of Halide code and remove all pre-existing scheduling. (I generally do this using #if 0 at present, but there will be a better way to choose between explicit scheduling and auto scheduling when using Generators. Using if statements with a parameter in C++ code is also a good way to go.)

Take all output `Funcs` and call the `Func::estimate` method to give approximate bounds for those outputs. (The auto scheduler may use the estimate as a minimum however so constraints can be introduced via vectorization.)

Then make sure you have a `Pipeline`, not a `Func`, and call the auto_schedule method. (A `Pipeline` can be constructed from a `Func`.) The `Pipeline` can then be run via `realize` or compiled via `compile_to_file` or similar.

Some scheduling can be mixed in with the auto scheduler, such as asserting strides and extents. But if there is any complicated scheduling already applied, the auto scheduler will likely assert.